# Probability of a car accident given that a man is driving (Bayes formula)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I came across the following exercise illustrating the Bayes formula:

> Let's consider the events: F = {female driver}, G = {male driver}, and
>   A = {car accident}. We also know that `P(A|F) = a`, `P(A|G) = b`, and
>   `P(F) = P(G) = 1/2`. Compute `P(A)`.

Then the solution simply gives the formula for computing `P(A)`. But I don't understand the meaning of events such as $A \cap F$. When we define the events F, G and A, what is the sample space $\Omega$? Is it the cartesian product of two sample spaces $ \Omega_1 = \{$female driver, male driver$\}$ and  $ \Omega_2 = \{$accident, no accident$\}$?

In this case, the events should be defined as follows: `F` = $\{$ (female driver, accident), (female driver, no accident) $\}$, and `A`= $\{$ (female driver, accident), (male driver, accident) $\}$. Therefore, events such as $A \cap F$ can be properly defined: $A \cap F$ = $\{$ (female driver, accident) $\}$.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: the title is incredibly sexist-sounding.

Comment: Your understanding looks correct to me.

Comment: Community bot has bumped this about twenty times in hopes of an answer, yet there was an answer, and nobody had upvoted it, so I've edited the answer to provide latex and upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Marginalization:
$$
    P(A) = P(A,G) + P(A,F)               
$$
Chain Rule:
$$
    P(A) = P(A|G) P(G) + P(A|F) P(F)     
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
    P(A) &= b(1/2) + a(1/2)\\
     &= (a+b)/2\\
\end{align}
$$
I'm guessing this would be the given solution. If not, please specify. It would help explain the solution better.

Answer (score 0):

Hint -

In this question intersection of two events not given. You have to find that first.

For example -

$P(A|F) = \frac{P(A \cap F)}{P(F)}$